# Write text next to text in a input if contient "//"JS

Tags: javascript, html, input, placeholder

I would like to display a placeholder (or grey text) in JavaScript next to a text in an entry if it contains "//".

(The idea did not come from me, I put it in credit here)
https://dribbble.com/shots/14433695-Task-composer-interactions

Do you have any idea how to display text in an entry that already contains text?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution. It uses 2 inputs and jQuery to manipulate the DOM (but vanilla would work fine as well). It's not incredibly robust but accomplishes what your question asked. Because the input gets auto-sized, I am importing and using a monospace font, and using the `ch` unit to measure the length of the input.

```js
$('.faux-element .main-input').on('input', function(e) {
  let l = $(this).val().length;
  $(this).css({
    width: l + "ch"
  });
  if ($(this).val().includes('//')) {
    let second = $(this).parent().find('.secondary-input').attr('readonly', false);
    second.attr('placeholder', 'Another place to type').focus();

  }
}).focus()
```

```css
.faux-element {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.faux-element input,
.faux-element input:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

.secondary-input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class='faux-element'>
  <input class='main-input' /><input class='secondary-input' readonly />
</div>
```